# Resizng data disk on Alicloud

Tags: disk

I have a production server running CentOS 6.9 on Alicloud in China. Instance is of `ecs.sn1.3xlarge` type. Recently one of my data disk became filled-up. So I decided to resize the volume and followed the step by step instructions available on this page: https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/25452.html.

Here are steps that I followed:

1. Resized disk form console
2. Rebooted system (Rebooting system didn't resized/populated disk on system)
3. umount disk
4. Run fdisk on desired disk
5. e2fsck -f /dev/vdb1 # check the file system
6. resize2fs /dev/vdb1 # resize the file system

Thank you in Advance

Comment: Please clarify the actual question?

Comment: Disk hasn't been expanded after performing steps written in alicloud guide/documentation..